# How can I get a FacetGrid to plot a variable across a time series? Chart is clustering to the right

Tags: python, pandas, plot, seaborn

This is my first question here - so go easy ;-)

I've searched and haven't been able to find exactly what I'm looking for, so I was hoping to get some help here.

I'm having a problem getting the timeseries data to plot correctly. It seems the data is all clustering to the right of the plots as opposed to being spread across the subplot from left to right.

The dataframe is as follows:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 216 entries, 0 to 215
Data columns (total 5 columns):
date        216 non-null datetime64[ns]
ticker      216 non-null object
capital     216 non-null float64
income      216 non-null float64
multiple    216 non-null float64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(3), object(1)
memory usage: 8.5+ KB
None
```

A sample of the data here: [screenshot of dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKXUv.jpg)

The code I've used is as follows:

```
# Initialize a grid of plots with an Axes for each walk
grid = sns.FacetGrid(dfs3, col="ticker", hue="capital", col_wrap=6,size=1.5)

# Draw a horizontal line to show the starting point
grid.map(plt.axhline, y=0, ls=":", c=".5")

# Draw a line plot to show the trajectory of capital across time
grid.map(plt.plot, "date", "capital", marker="o", ms=4)

# Adjust the arrangement of the plots
grid.fig.tight_layout(w_pad=1)
#show
plt.show()
```

The output of the code is as follows:

[FacetGrid output example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXcly.jpg)

I'm hoping to get the data to plot from left to right rather than cluster on the right side of the subplots.  Also, any help in tidying up the datetime on the x-axis would be appreciated.

Thanks! I hope this question is clear enough. Any feedback appreciated on the question format and etc. would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question does not provide enough information for others to recreate the data and solve. Please read through how to make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). A screenshot is usually not sufficient for others to create the data.frame to manipulate.

Comment: Hi Steve.. thank you for the feedback.. i'll amend the question to make it easier. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding you question about the x-axis: 
In order for you to see the x-axis properly you should rotate the labels using the rotation argument on your axis, like so:

```
grid.set_xticklabels(rotation=90)
```

This will give you a 90-degree tilt of your ticklabels.

Regarding the clustered data: Maybe you should try to limit the date-range of your plot as it appears to have no data until your very last dates, hence the clustering.

Comment: thank you - the rotation of the labels did indeed show the date range goes from 2001 to 2017.. That is weird as the date range is 2014-2017.  how do you set a limit on the date range of the plot?

Comment: say you want to select the date rage between 2014-17, then you can filter your dataframe like so: df = df[(df['date'] > '2013-12-31') & (df['date'] <= '2017-12-31')]. If you are working with Jupyter maybe restart your kernel for the analysis as this clears the memory and then rerun your code.

Comment: glad i could help :) if this solves you problem you can accept an answer on stackoverflow by clicking the green checkmark